# function beforeFilter is not working in cakephp2.0

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using CakePHP 2.0. I have used the following code in my AppController.php

```
 public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->setOrderConfigValues();
 }
 public function setOrderConfigValues(){
   $this->Session->write('Order.session', $this->Session->read('Config.userAgent'));
 }
```

but its not working. When I apply die() inside the function, it displays the value, but, when using normally, function is not called.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have `beforeFilter()` override in some other controller, but you forgot to add `parent::beforeFilter();`